# Org-mode: Keep cursor on first character of heading (clean view & word wrap/visual line modes)

Tags: org-mode

I have a document like:

```
* 1st Heading
  * 2nd Heading
    * 3rd Heading...
```

When I have my cursor positioned on the '3' of the third heading and press TAB, the 3rd heading expands as expected, but the cursor position moves to the position shown as 'X' below:

```
* 1st Heading
  * 2nd Heading
  X * 3rd Heading
      * 4th Heading
```

When I again press TAB, the 4th heading collapses as expected but the cursor remains at the position shown as 'X' below:

```
* 1st Heading
  * 2nd Heading
  X * 3rd Heading...
```

Is there a way to keep the cursor on the first character of the heading when I press TAB?

Org-mode: 7.01g /// Emacs: 23.2.1 /// Debian stable - Squeeze /// Clean view mode /// Word wrap/visual line mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest updating your Org-mode to 7.7.

I just tested your exact use-case (both using TAB and SHIFT-TAB), my cursor remained on the same character, even when that tree was hidden.